# Can I construct more than one type of object from same class data with the help of constructor in Java?

Tags: java

suppose I have a class (let's say class name is "MyClass") with data (a,b,c,d) can define two constructor, one used to create to object1 using data (a,b,c) and another constructor to create object2 using data (a,c,d).  In this case all data type are same lets say double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

The two constructors would have the same signature: `MyClass(double, double, double)`.

In order to distinguish the two, you'd have to give them different names, and you can't do that with constructors.

You can however create differently named static methods to use instead of constructors, e.g.

```
public class MyClass {
    // fields here
    public static MyClass forObject1(double a, double b, double c) {
        return new MyClass(a, b, c, 0);
    }
    public static MyClass forObject2(double a, double c, double d) {
        return new MyClass(a, 0, c, d);
    }
    private MyClass(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
        // assign to fields here
    }
    // methods here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it.

You can use overloaded constructors, just as you would use overloaded methods. You just need to make sure that you are overloading them properly such that there is no ambiguity for the JVM when it instantiates an object.

Comment: But ambiguity is bound to happen, you see my question, both object need three parameter (abc and acd), and all the parameter (abcd are of same type that is double).

Comment: You have to add another parameter to indicate which object you wish to create in that case. A boolean will be enough since you only have two options.

Answer (score 0):

You can or cannot do it depending on what the types of `object1` and `object2` are.

Let's say that you have a class `Foo`. If you want `object` and `object2` both of type `Foo`, then you can achieve this, like this:

```
class Foo{
    //some methods....

    public Foo(int arg1forObj1, int arg2ForObj1...){
        //some code    
    }

    public Foo(String arg1forObj2, String arg2ForObj2...){
        //some code    
    }
}
```

Do note that the two constructors should **not** take the same type of arguments, otherwise they will be ambiguous.

---

However you want `object1` and `object2` to be of different types, no you can't achieve this. When you do `new Foo()`(ie create an instance of the class), the instance will always be of a `Foo` type.